# Read a requested URL path without a predefined route, in Golang

Tags: go

I am creating a Go web app in which I need to read a URL like example.com/person/(any_name)

How can I read and print any_name?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't have enough information to understand the problem, we'd need to see what you've tried so far. If you're new to Go, you'll probably want to read [A Tour Of Go](https://tour.golang.org/list), [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) and [Go By Example](https://gobyexample.com/).

Comment: What do you mean by "handle a URL"?  What have you tried? Are you using a router? Which one?

Comment: Please read the official documentation before asking any questions like this.

Comment: It's a fine question. I shouldn't need a handler with a predefined "route" just to get information about a server request. There should be a more direct way to get request info for any/all requests, and then do whatever I want with the information.

Answer (score 5):

You should look into using gorilla/mux package for what you are trying to do.
An excerpt from the package github shows https://github.com/gorilla/mux

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/products/{key}", ProductHandler)
r.HandleFunc("/articles/{category}/", ArticlesCategoryHandler)
r.HandleFunc("/articles/{category}/{id:[0-9]+}", ArticleHandler)
```

Comment: "The Gorilla project has been archived, and is no longer under active maintainenance."

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at this page https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/ there are examples of what I think you are after.

You want a handler with name person and then extract (any_name) and handle it accordingly to each person. One of the examples shows how to do it with title which is the same principle.

```
func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    title := r.URL.Path[len("/view/"):]
    p, _ := loadPage(title)
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("view.html")
    t.Execute(w, p)
}
```

Instead of /view/ you got /person/ and title is what (any_name) is in your case.

`r.URL.Path[len("/view/"):]` will take everything from `r.URL.Path` but start `len("/view/")` bytes into the slice.